# How to set title on navigation controller added as more navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have 6 view controllers and I am using UiTabbar view. so om main screen the number of 4 viewcontrollers are shown in tabs and OS create another one and named it as more.

On clicking more it shown me 2 of my view controller inside UiTableView. and when I click on them it opens up my viewcontroller with the Navigation controller on its top with back button labeled as More

for complete understanding see below picture 
[image]

> **What I Want:** Here you can see that More is just visible with the Back button, I want to only show the Back button and I want center
>   title with the label of "Offers" in white text

**Update1:**

> Calling this method in ViewWillDisplay()

```
    func setUpNavBar(title: String,backBtn : String) -> Void {


    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    let titleStr = title

    self.navigationItem.title = titleStr
    self.navigationItem.titleView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red


    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.textColor = .white
    titleLabel.text = titleStr
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel



    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = CommonUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: AppColor.colorTwentyScaleDarkerOfColorPrimaryDark)

    if var textAttributes = navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes {
        textAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In OffersViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.title = "Offers"
    }
```

In the previous ViewController

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.title = ""
    }
```

You can also try this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.textColor = .white
        titleLabel.text = self.title
        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
}
```

Comment: this will show title in black color and it will not remove More from backbutton

Comment: Did you write the code for viewWillDisappear in previousViewController? It should work. Further, you can change the text color as the edited answer. You may have to specify a frame for the label

Comment: this is not working dude. It only works in the view controller I add them into Navigation controller. 

but this one is having navigation controller added by the OS. Did you get my point ?

Comment: hey @A.s.ALI did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is done in view did load on the view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title"
}
```